# Running Axis2 web service client is generating an error at the client and the server side

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

The client side error is :

```
    0 [main] INFO org.ws.call.BankWSCallClass - callChequeCertificationWS...
702 [main] INFO org.ws.call.BankWSCallClass - callChequeVerificationWS... serviceCreated
702 [main] INFO org.ws.call.BankWSCallClass - callChequeVerificationWS... portCreated
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method chequeCertification
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.ws.server.implementation.ChequeProcessingServiceStub.chequeCertification(ChequeProcessingServiceStub.java:911)
    at org.ws.call.BankWSCallClass.callChequeCertificationWS(BankWSCallClass.java:53)
    at org.ws.call.BankWSCallClass.main(BankWSCallClass.java:106)
```

While the server side error is

```
    [#|2012-05-10T15:52:32.390+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=79;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|[ERROR] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method chequeCertification
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.ws.server.implementation.ChequeProcessingService.chequeCertification(ChequeProcessingService.java:18)
    ... 37 more
|#]
```

Overview: i am using springsourcetool (similar to eclipse) as the development IDE. Glassfish as the application server. the web service is ChequeProcessingService, i generated the .aar file and deployed it under axis2 web project of glassfish. the client side code is generated using axis2 code generator tool, it is simply calling the web service method 'chequeCertification' that has a javabean request parameter and returns another javabean response object.

Axis2 version that am using is 1.6.2 with JDK 1.7

Kindly advice from where may come this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real problem is this NullPointerException in your server:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.ws.server.implementation.ChequeProcessingService.chequeCertification
       (ChequeProcessingService.java:18)
```

This is probably in some code that you wrote, so it's not possible to say exactly what the problem is.

The client error is probably just a reaction to the bad response returned from the server when the server threw an exception. You should consider adding some logic to catch AxisFaults that are thrown when you call a web service, so that you could for example print a more suitable error message.

Comment: Problem solved. as you mentioned, it was a null pointer exception issue on a javabean parameter at the server side. actually am new at axis2 and i didn't know how to set the javabean at client side before calling the webservice...and this made it reach the server as null parameter...